# Sequence of data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have sequence of data in MATLAB: data1, data2, data3,.... I want to print them one after one. I am stuck on that.

```
clear; clc;
data1=[1,2];
data2=[3,4];
n=[1,2];
for i=1:length(n)
    fname(i,:)=sprintf('data%d',n(i));
end
```

Comment: Did you try `disp(data1)`?

Comment: When I `disp(data1)` it displays the matrix but, I want to display all the matrices I have and I want it to do by a cycle because they are many like 70, and `disp(fname(1,:))` does not work it displays just data1.

Comment: Why would you have 70 separate data variables rather than a single 2-dimensional array (or cell array, if the variables are different lengths) that you can easily loop over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
clear; clc;
data1=[1,2];
data2=[3,4];
n=[1,2];
for i=1:length(n)
    eval(['data' num2str(n(i))])
end
```

Comment: please accept the answer if the answer is satisfactory.

Comment: Sure, it just wanted me to wait 2 minutes. Thanks again, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution not involving the use of `eval` could be the following.

Basically it consists of the following steps:

- Get the list of data in the Workspace (with `who` function)
- Identify the data to be printed (using `regexp` to identfy the variables names of the form `datax`where `x` is a number)
- save these variables in a temporary `.mat` file
- load the `.mat` file in a struct which allows to have only the variables to be printed
- exploit the `dynamic field names` to get access to the variables

This the code:

```
% Define some data
data1=[1,2];
data2=[3,4];
data3=rand(5)
data4a=rand(5)
dataaaa3=rand(5)
var_1=1
b=2
% Get the list of data in the Workspace
str=who
% Identify the data to be printed
var_to_print=regexp(str,'data\d$')
idx=~cellfun(@isempty,var_to_print)
% Down select the variables to be printed
str{idx}
% Generate a temporary ".mat" filename
tmp_name=[tempname '.mat']
% Save the data to be printed in the temporary ".mat" file
save(tmp_name,str{idx})
% Load the data to be printed into a struct
v=load(tmp_name)
% Get the names of the varaibles to be printed
f_name=fieldnames(v)
% print the value of the variables
for i=1:length(f_name)
   [char(f_name(i)) ' = ']
   v.(f_name{i})
end
% Move the temporary ".mat" file in the recycle folder
recycle('on')
delete(tmp_name)
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'

Comment: You could also do `save(tmp_name, 'data*')`

Comment: @Suever `save(tmp_name, 'data*')` will also save variables such as `data4a`, `dataaaa3` (ref., to the variable in my answer) while the OP said the variables names are `data1`, `data2`.

Comment: Ah yea good point. You could also probably do then `save(tmp_name, '-regexp', '^data\d+$')`

Comment: @Suever nice solution! I'm a beginner with `regexp`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I might use this temporary `.mat` files.